# Jenkins is unable to download artifact from github

Tags: git, jenkins

I have tried below methords
given my github credentials in the source code management tab.
added git webhooks. But still seeing below error. Please help out

```
Started by user User
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/first_git_job
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/user/test2.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/first_git_job # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/user/test2.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.17.1'
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/user/test2.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/user/test2.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Seems it can't find any credentials ("No credentials specified"). Refer to [plugin documentation](No credentials specified) or [pipeline documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/). Show your commands, not just the logs.